# Lagrange Multiplier Test (Score Test) reliability at low likelihood

Tags: maximum-likelihood, lagrange-multipliers

The Lagrange Multiplier Test (Score Test) in the multivariate case has the following formula:

$$ LM = [\underline{s}(\underline{\theta_0})]^T*[Var(\underline{\theta_0})]^{-1}*\underline{s}(\underline{\theta_0}) \sim \chi^2_q,  $$

where underscores denote vectors, and $\underline{\theta_0}$ denotes the set of parameters of the null. Under the null, LM has a Chi-Squared distribution with q degrees of freedom. The LM test evaluates the slope (score) at the hypothesized parameter, and if the slope (score) is much different from the slope at the MLE estimate, this suggests to reject the null.

However, if the likelihood distribution has a normal shape, as taught by Ben Lambert in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ck7EChMRQ9o&list=PLwJRxp3blEvb7P-7po9AxuBwquPv75LjU&index=48), the slope in the tails is more similar to the zero-value at the center of the distribution at the MLE. This raises two questions to me:

a) Is it impossible for a likelihood distribution to have a normal shape?
b) If yes, how does is likelihood different in shape from a pdf?
c) If not, what is the implication of having a small LM statistic in the tails?